# btreepage and MessageQueueSend wait events in DB

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

Team,
Can someone provide me more context on waitevents for btreepage and MessageQueueSend.
Whenever the query executing these two events are showing in top list at same time autovacuum was triggering many of the toast tables same time.
Verified query execution plan of the query, its taking indexes scan and it took 1 sec.

Can you provide more details about these events .
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be resource contention.

With the default setting of `autovacuum_max_workers` there can never be more than three autovacuum workers at the same time, so if you messed with that setting, that may be your problem.

If three autovacuum workers are enough to impact CPU or I/O performance, get stronger hardware.

More detailed advice is impossible to give, since you are telling us almost nothing about your system and your configuration.